# php mysql left join where clause error

Tags: mysql, join

With the following tables

posts

- id
- post_id
- user_id

comments

- id
- post_id
- comment_id
- user_id
- deleted

replies

- id
- post_id
- reply_id
- user_id
- deleted

I am trying to get every comment and reply from each post.post_id and post.user_id='x' and the comment  or reply is not deleted(0)

this is what i have tried

```
SELECT *
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN comments c ON p.id=c.post_id
LEFT JOIN replies r ON p.id=r.post_id
WHERE p.user_id=$user_id
&& c.deleted='0' && r.deleted='0'
```

which does not work...

Comment: Try using `AND` instead of `&&`

Comment: If `deleted=0` means deleted comment, then this will show all deleted-posts - deleted-comments combinations.

Comment: returns 0 which is not the result.
edit: so how can i make it do what i want?

Comment: @fxuser: What does `0` mean? Deleted or not deleted?

Comment: 0 means not deleted -- ps : damn its midnight i cant even write properly...

Comment: @fxuser: OK, try now my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A post may have comments or not. Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.

A post may have replies or not. Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` in that join too.

When `LEFT JOIN` is used, a  condition like `WHERE comments.deleted = 0` that includes a field (from the right table (`comments`) in the LEFT JOIN), the LEFT JOIN is cancelled. So, we should put this condition in the `ON` clause and not in the `WHERE`.

```
SELECT *
FROM posts p
  LEFT JOIN comments c
    ON p.post_id = c.post_id
    AND c.deleted = 0
  LEFT JOIN replies r
    ON p.post_id = r.post_id
    AND r.deleted = 0  
WHERE p.user_id = $user_id
```

---

Thinking more clearly, the above will show what the question describes but in cases with say, 4 comments and 3 replies, 12 rows will be returned (3x4). Which is probably not wanted. The following 2nd try does not have such issue.

I don't see a `post.text` or `comment.text` or `reply.text` in the tables but anyway, you'll get the idea. You can remove the 3 `text` lines if not appropriate.

```
  ( SELECT p.post_id     AS post_id 
         , 0             AS type
         , p.post_id     AS id
         , p.text        AS text
    FROM posts p
    WHERE p.user_id = $user_id
  )
UNION ALL
  ( SELECT p.post_id     AS post_id 
         , 1             AS type
         , c.comment_id  AS id
         , c.text        AS text
    FROM posts p
      JOIN comments c
        ON p.post_id = c.post_id
    WHERE p.user_id = $user_id
      AND c.deleted = 0
  )
UNION ALL
  ( SELECT p.post_id     AS post_id 
         , 2             AS type
         , r.reply_id    AS id
         , r.text        AS text
    FROM posts p
      JOIN replies r
        ON p.post_id = r.post_id
    WHERE p.user_id = $user_id
      AND r.deleted = 0
  )
ORDER BY post_id
       , post_type
       , id
```

The 0,1,2 stand for post, comment, reply.

Comment: i tried the select query but it still counts the deleted comments (have value 1)

Comment: @fxuser: Do you want to count comments and replies? Or show them?

Comment: im going to leave it.I am going to show the deleted items and just show a message.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the deleted check **into the join clause**. This should do it:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN comments c ON c.post_id = p.post_id AND NOT c.deleted
LEFT JOIN replies r ON r.post_id = p.post_id AND NOT r.deleted
WHERE p.user_id = $user_id
```

Note: Not sure if c.post_id joins to p.id or p.post_id - chenge the on clause as required

Comment: still counts the deleted comments or posts.. if i remove either one of the joins it will show correct data from comments or replies but both of them just dont work...